# Plotting vertical bars and series (x= y=) together using SAS

Tags: plot, visualization, sas

Here is a graphical output that I'm trying to mimic. I want a series AND vertical bars plotted simultaneously

[image]

However the SAS has a compatibility issue with plotting series and vbar together. Is there a way to plot my data as above?

Comment: I'm not a graphing expert by any means, but I remember seeing two examples using different techniques for doing something like this.  The first was to create two different charts, but save one to use as a background image for the second.  The second approach was to create an annotate data set to draw the lines of the vertical bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the V9.2 GBarLine example at:

http://robslink.com/SAS/democd30/aaaindex.htm

If you have SAS version 9.2 or above you should be fine.